# Keeping my changes up to date with OSM

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, merge, update, josm

One year ago, we exported data from OpenStreetMap. We added attributes and cut some segments with JOSM.
Now, we want to update those files (.osm) to the current state of OpenStreetMap.
How can we merge our local data and a planetfile for instance ?

We can copy our attributes to the new planet file (using the OSM ID correspondence), but we loose the new segments we created. What can we do merge both ?

Comment: Keep Local Database in sync with OSM https://ircama.github.io/osm-carto-tutorials/updating-data/

Comment: I tried that but since we have some new segments (with negative IDs), Osmosis doesn't work well.

Comment: Maybe osmium-tool can handle them. Just a guess, I haven't tried it. Alternatively create a diff against the old planet, import the new planet and apply your diff again. You can also try asking at http://help.openstreetmap.org/

Comment: is there a reason not to have pushed your changes back to OSM? you have essentially "forked" the project and must bear the costs accordingly

Comment: @IanTurton Not really... But it's a bit too late now.